# Best safe 2FA for Windows desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, authentication, two-factor-authentication

Any way to use Windows Hello as a multifactor authenticator?

I want to use my fingerprint biometrics as a 2FA.

I tried to do it with Authy, for example, but it doesn't have the Windows Hello biometrics protection in it. There is no Google Authenticator or Microsoft Authenticator for Windows Desktop either.